# Searching PubMed via python vs web

Tags: python, biopython, pubmed

I am trying to search articles on PubMed. I was hoping to get the same articles when searching the website, test out the search terms and then use it via python code. I tried a few libraries but the results are different from the web.

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline
term = "Cyber Security"
Entrez.email = "A.N.Other@example.com"  # Replaced for obvious reasons
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=term, retmax=5)
esearch_record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
print(f"Records found: {esearch_record['Count']}")
```

returns -

> Records found: 15442

Another code that I tried -

```
from metapub import PubMedFetcher
fetch = PubMedFetcher()
keyword = "Cyber Security"
pmids = fetch.pmids_for_query(keyword, retmax=100000)
print(len(pmids))
```

Number of results -

> 15442

While when I search on website I receive `15,045` results. I am trying to find out what I am not doing correctly and why are the results different?

[image: Pubmed results]

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the *results should be the same?*

Comment: The python code I showed is to use the APIs for PubMed. So the results returned should be the same. I am fetching the PMIDs that are in green in the screenshot.

Comment: "The python code I showed is to use the APIs for PubMed. So the results returned should be the same." I'm sorry -- **why** should they? Who gave you this guarantee? Where is this written? And who knows, you are using some web portal, is there anything you are filtering? (e.g. implicit filtering by dates?)

Comment: I did not use any filters neither implicit nor explicit. And API should return the same results as the front end as these are based on the "eutils interaction library, handling the metadata of pubmed papers" https://pypi.org/project/metapub/. https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Entrez.html the first line it says "Provides code to access NCBI over the WWW." Why should the results be any different?

Comment: I would guess that an article can be assigned multiple PubMed IDs. This is possible with DOIs, could also be the case with PubMed IDs. Also, the API that services the website vs remote queries are separately maintained. In the past, there has been desync between them.